SAS Base: KEEP Statement and KEEP = Option
Hi I am new to SAS and I came across a SAS Base Programming Reference Sheet. In the section of The Data Step: Controlling Variable Output, the example code in the box confuses me.
Is the example code wrong? Because the column store_name in the KEEP statement has never been referenced so SAS should not be able to execute the KEEP statement.
I tested out the code using the following code and got an error:

DATA work.cars (KEEP = Model Type);
    SET sashelp.cars (DROP = Invoice);
    KEEP MSRP drivetrain;
RUN;

The error messages says
"WARNING: The variable Model in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced.
WARNING: The variable Type in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced."
Does that mean the example code is wrong?

Whether the example code is wrong or not depends on the context. It may well be that it is an example to highlight this very behavior (the Warning). However, your interpretation is correct.

I'm confused, you mention the column store_name but it is not used in your code.  I would think the point of the example is to show that you can use both a KEEP statement and a KEEP dataset option in the same step, in which case apparently both lists of variables to keep will be applied.  I don't think I've ever done that before.

The KEEP= dataset option on the OUTPUT dataset is applied to the dataset as defined by the DATA step.  So in this case KEEP statement in the data step means that only the MSRP and DRIVETRAIN variables will be output.  So referencing any other variables in the KEEP= dataset option on the WORK.CARS output dataset name will issue the warning you saw.
Note you can control how SAS treats such things using the DKROCOND (and for input datasets the DKRICOND) system option.
Examples:
1    options dkrocond=nowarn;
2    DATA work.cars (KEEP = Model Type);
3        SET sashelp.cars (DROP = Invoice);
4        KEEP MSRP drivetrain;
5    RUN;

NOTE: There were 428 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CARS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.CARS has 428 observations and 0 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


6    options dkrocond=error;
7    DATA work.cars (KEEP = Model Type);
8        SET sashelp.cars (DROP = Invoice);
9        KEEP MSRP drivetrain;
10   RUN;

ERROR: The variable Model in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced.
ERROR: The variable Type in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.CARS may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 0 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.CARS was not replaced because this step was stopped.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


The comment on 'never referenced' implies the variable doesn't exist (not literally referenced in the code).
This example seems to imply the KEEP statement is applied prior to the KEEP= dataset option. So since the KEEP statement is applied, none of the variables in the KEEP = are available to for the data set so it throws a warning message. Otherwise, it would keep the variables. You can test this by adding those variables to the keep statement.
Because the keep statement and option do not align they actually cancel each other out and there is no data written out.
*keeps model type, with model/type included on KEEP statement.
DATA work.cars (KEEP = Model Type);
    SET sashelp.cars (DROP = Invoice);
    KEEP MSRP drivetrain MODEL TYPE;
RUN;

*keeps model and type with no reference;
DATA work.cars (KEEP = Model Type);
    SET sashelp.cars (DROP = Invoice);
RUN;

